# Discourage question askers from adding a question comment unless someone else has commented first

Tags: feature-request, questions, comments

In [Is there any good OpenDocument library in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455849/is-there-any-good-opendocument-library-in-ruby) the question asker has said:

> I would like to generate a OpenDocument format in Ruby programming language. Is there any good library for this?

Then, in a comment the OP added:

> something like prawn but for OpenDocument github.com/sandal/prawn

Unless this comment was in reply to another comment that has disappeared, the OP shouldn't add a comment, but edit the original question. It makes it easier to read.

Stack Exchange should either:

1. Disallow the question asker from adding a question comment unless someone else has commented first.
2. Say "Are you sure you want to do this?" when adding a question comment unless someone else has commented first.

Comment: Err.. just edit it into the question. It's not a big deal. :|

Comment: @brucelee: What do I do about the comment? Just leave it there? Flag the comment? Flag the question asking for diamond mod magic to make the comment disappear?

Comment: I just flagged it as obsolete, since it is now edited into the answer. Making this question localized. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @brucelee: It as in the comment, not the question, right? Also, shouldn't the emoticon be be `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`?

Comment: I flagged the comment, so it's in the queue right now. My forearm earlier? Who knows? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @brucelee: it seems like your forearm is getting mangled by the SO mark-up :-)

Comment: This is the trouble with shopping questions, no end of late "oh, it should be like this" or "hmm, don't like that" comments.  They should be closed as off topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments are not that much of an issue - they are noise, true, but multiple comments are folded together which makes it bearable. In general, they are meant to be left alone, unless they are particularly disruptive.

In cases where a user provides a follow-up to their question in a comment or, worse, in an answer you could try the following:

- Add a comment of your own, pointing out the *Edit* link under their question and asking them to add the content to the question, then delete their post. Then, *please*, allow some time for the user to do that. New users should be given the opportunity to correct their own mistakes, as a way to learn the SO way.
- If you have sufficient reputation, edit the question yourself if the OP does not do so in a reasonable time frame.
- If there is no response from the OP, you can leave comments alone. On the other hand, you should probably flag question follow-ups that are posted as answers with the "Not an answer" flag, so that they will be cleaned-up by a moderator.

I don't think that any additional hard limits need to be placed on comments.

I might agree with an informational message for new users that would point out the *Edit* link when they first try to post a comment to their own question.

And I would *definitely* agree with anything that educates a new user when they try to follow-up on their own question by adding a (non-)answer.